# How to use a large number of variables in a set using limited memory?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, set

I would like to use a large number of variables in a set and then do some calculations.
Each variable has to vary by 20 points and each time I launch my program, my memory dont follow...
Here what I want to do:

```
mySet = set((a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10) for a1 in np.arange(1,2,0.05) for a2 in np.arange(1,2,0.05) for a3 in np.arange(1,2,0.05) for a4 in np.arange(1,2,0.05)  for a5 in np.arange(1,2,0.05)  for a6 in np.arange(1,2,0.05)  for a7 in np.arange(1,2,0.05) for a8 in np.arange(1,2,0.05) for a9 in np.arange(1,2,0.05) for a10 in np.arange(1,2,0.05) )

for element in mySet :
    calculation using arrays
```

Today, I just decrease the number of points to achieve (5 points instead of 20 points for each variable), but I don't know how to reach the 20 (step of 0.05).

Do I have to split my calculations?

Is there another way to do this calculation?

Thank you!

Comment: Is it necessary for your program to iterate over all variables, each with 20 different values? It seems computationally infeasible to iterate over `20^10` lists or even store them in memory.

Comment: Or rather tell us what is actual problem that you are trying to solve.

Comment: You could use generators, so you won't run out of memory, but as @Raj said it won't never finish

Comment: Not necessary bu it's better. I know it's a lot, but I don't care if it takes 1 week. My principal problem is about the memory, not the number of possibilities.

Comment: Ok thanks. so how do I use a generator for my calculations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write this as a generator, just remove the `set` keyword.

```
mySet = ((a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9,a10) for a1 in np.arange(1,2,0.05) 
                                          for a2 in np.arange(1,2,0.05) 
                                          for a3 in np.arange(1,2,0.05) 
                                          for a4 in np.arange(1,2,0.05)  
                                          for a5 in np.arange(1,2,0.05)  
                                          for a6 in np.arange(1,2,0.05)  
                                          for a7 in np.arange(1,2,0.05) 
                                          for a8 in np.arange(1,2,0.05) 
                                          for a9 in np.arange(1,2,0.05) 
                                          for a10 in np.arange(1,2,0.05))
for element in mySet :
    calculation using arrays
```

---

Edit: You can write this more efficiently by using `itertools`.

```
from itertools import product

mySet = product(np.arange(1, 2, 0.05), repeat=10)
```